# How to know where winget installed a program?

Tags: windows-11, winget

I had installed Zotero using `winget install Zotero.Zotero` and it installed fine in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zotero`. But when I run `winget upgrade`, it shows two Zotero versions, like so:

```
Name   Id            Version Available Source
---------------------------------------------
Zotero Zotero.Zotero 6.0.10  6.0.13    winget
Zotero Zotero.Zotero 6.0.9   6.0.13    winget
2 upgrades available.
```

I have verified that the currently installed Zotero version is `6.0.13`. Since I have had prior installations of Zotero with and without winget, I think, these entries might reflect those installations. So, I wanted to uninstall / remove these without removing version `6.0.13`, currently installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zotero`.

My question is, how do I make winget show the installation directories for these two versions, so that I can manually remove them?

Comment: A side note, vote for this feature: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/2298

Answer (score 20):

## Update 2023-04-17

It seems winget version `v1.5.1081-preview` and above (those including [PR3128](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/pull/3128)), include info on default directories by running `winget --info`.

[image: output from winget --info]

There's also an open issue to be able to list the directories per app ([Issue 2298](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/2298)).

Regarding Zotero itself, I couldn't find a package with ID `Zotero.Zotero`, but did find [DigitalScholar.Zotero](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/tree/0b08dbffe64576f87977de00e2e4bf0dff9532e4/manifests/d/DigitalScholar/Zotero/6.0.9).  That shows that the default installer's used, so the default path would be the same as the app's (from hunting around their docs this seems to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zotero`, though I've not seen anything explicit).

Note: It's possible that your additional version of `Zotero.Zotero` doesn't exist on disk; but only exists in WinGet's database (e.g. if it were installed then the path deleted without WinGet being aware).  See "Failed Attempt to Hunt Out Metadata" for info on how to query that database).

---

## Original Answer

The exact location depends on the package & so far as I can tell there's currently no way to fetch that info for all installed winget packages.

For those which don't have installers, but are just files downloaded, they're put under a folder under: `%localappdata%\microsoft\winget\packages`

Where there's an exe with a portable command alias (i.e. to avoid having to add each exe's path to your PATH variable), a symlink is created. That symlink is held in  `%localappdata%\Microsoft\WinGet\Links\`.

Note: Some apps' manifests may specificy a default install directory.  That's given in their `InstallLocation` property (see [schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/winget-cli/master/schemas/JSON/manifests/v1.4.0/manifest.installer.1.4.0.json)).

---

## Failed Attempt to Hunt Out Metadata

I wondered if you could find the path under which WinGet stores the metadata of packages installed... I couldn't - but notes below in case this helps others hunt deeper (my conclusion is that WinGet doesn't remember where it installs things, only that it has installed them / what version it installed; everything else is left to the default installer).

You can get the path for its settings file by running `winget settings` then looking at the path of the `settings.json` file that this opens.  For me this was: `C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`

By poking around in that directory I found a SQLLite DB: `C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\installed.db`.

We can query this file/database using the below PowerShell:

```
# Load the System.Data.SQLite.dll assembly.  This is likely already somewhere on your machine, but if you can't find it, see https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\System.Data.SQLite.dll'

# Update this path with your install.db path
$installDbPath = 'C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\installed.db'

# create a connection to this db
$con = [System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection]::new("Data Source=$installDbPath")
$con.Open()

# Create and execute a query to list all tables (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623907/361842 for the SQL)
$command = $con.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = @"
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
  WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%'
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master
  WHERE type IN ('table','view')
ORDER BY 1;
"@
$data = [System.Data.DataSet]::new()
$adapter = [System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter]::new($command)
$adapter.Fill($data) | Out-Null
$data.Tables.Rows

# channels
# commands
# commands_map
# ids
# manifest
# manifest_metadata
# metadata
# monikers
# names
# norm_names
# norm_names_map
# norm_publishers
# norm_publishers_map
# pathparts
# pfns
# pfns_map
# productcodes
# productcodes_map
# tags
# tags_map
# versions

# Now repeat over the IDs table to give the IDs of all installed packages
$command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ids"
$data = [System.Data.DataSet]::new() # reset this to avoid appending
$adapter.Fill($data) #note: adapter has a reference to $command, so by updating the command text the adapter's command is automatically updated
$data.Tables.Rows | ft -AutoSize

# sadly I hunted through all the other tables but couldn't find any hint of an installation directory being stored here
```

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, not that it helped me actually find the installed package in question in my own circumstance but it helped me remember that WinGet is not a proper package manager and I shouldn't expect even basic functionality like this, alas. C'est la vie!

Comment: New manifest/schemas are now located [here](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/tree/master/schemas/JSON/manifests).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything matching among `winget` command line options.

But a partial workaround is to use [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line) command to search by executable name.

Like `where zotero`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The issue with `where` is that one needs to already have some idea as to where the program might have been installed or the program needs to have been added to path. In my case, neither was true. My issue was actually with how some programs fail to remove Registry entries when uninstalled, causing `winget` to report multiple versions. Those other Zotero versions weren't really installed.

Comment: On that note, this is what had helped me remove the other versions - https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1255#issuecomment-902873661.

Answer (score 0):

To the ones still looking for an answer, this works for me:

```
winget list -q $id | Out-Null
if ($?) {  echo "$id installed" }
```

Comment: This does not produce the installation location for me, only whether an `$id` is installed. I am using `winget v1.7.10661`.